# Please merge [google-plus-hangouts] and [google-hangout]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

They really are the same thing and have a comparable number of questions each.

- [google-plus-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts)
- [google-hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangout)

Comment: Which should be the "keeper"? I don't really use the program often enough to know.

Comment: The titlebar in a hangout says "Google+ Hangouts", as does the support page. (On Android it's just called "Hangouts".) So I think [tag:google-plus-hangouts] is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have merged the two tags and left [google-hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangout) as a synonym of [google-plus-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts).

[hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangout), which was originally a synonym of [google-hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-hangout) will now point at [google-plus-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts)